# Regularization of ConvLSTM inside Tensorflow estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm, tensorflow-estimator

I am using the convolutional LSTM cell from the contrib package of Tensorflow 1.5, inside the model_fn of an estimator. I would like to add L2 regularization to that cell. I tried the following code:

```
def myModelFn(features,labels,mode,params):
  trainingFlag = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  inferFlag = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT)

  dataShape = tuple(params['dataShape'])

  XSize,YSize,ZSize = dataShape[0],dataShape[1],dataShape[2]

  dataTensor = features['data']
  dataTensor = tf.reshape(dataTensor, [-1, XSize, YSize, ZSize, 1])

  labelTensor = tf.cast(labels['labels'], tf.int64)

  with tf.variable_scope('myModel'):
    normalizedData = tf.layers.batch_normalization(dataTensor,
                             center=True,
                             scale=True,
                             training=trainingFlag,
                             name='bnInput')

  with tf.variable_scope('module1'):
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv3d(normalizedData,
                         filters = 3,
                         kernel_size = (5,5,5),
                         kernel_regularizer=tf.nn.l2_loss,
                         name='conv3d_1')

    max1 = tf.layers.max_pooling3d(conv1,
                                pool_size = (5,5,5),
                                strides= (2,2,2),
                                name = 'max_1')
```

Here is where I create the convLSTM2D, to which I want to add L2 regularization:

```
  with tf.variable_scope('module2'):
    lstmInput = tf.transpose(max1, [0, 3, 1, 2, 4], 'lstmInput')

    lstmInputShape = lstmInput.shape.as_list()[2:]
    lstmInput = tf.unstack(lstmInput, axis=1)
    convLSTMNet = tf.contrib.rnn.ConvLSTMCell(conv_ndims=2,                                
                                           input_shape=lstmInputShape,
                                           output_channels=3,
                                           kernel_shape=[3, 3],
                                           use_bias=True,
                                           name='lstmConv2d')

  lstmKernelVars = [var for var in tf.trainable_variables(
    convLSTMNet.scope_name) if 'kernel' in var.name]

  tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(tf.nn.l2_loss,
                                         lstmKernelVars)

  lstmOutput, _ = tf.nn.static_rnn(convLSTMNet, lstmInput,
                                dtype=tf.float32)[-1]

  module2Output = tf.layers.flatten(lstmOutput, name='module2Output')

  with tf.variable_scope('module3'):
    dense1 = tf.layers.dense(module2Output, 150, name='dense1')
    dropout1 = tf.layers.dropout(dense1, 0.6, training=trainingFlag,
                          name='dropout1')
    dense2 = tf.layers.dense(dropout1,50,name='dense2')
    dropout2 = tf.layers.dropout(dense2, 0.5, training=trainingFlag,
                          name='dropout2')
    logits = tf.layers.dense(dropout2, 4, name='logits')

  outputLabel = tf.nn.softmax(logits,name='myLabel')

  predictions = {'prediction': tf.cast(tf.argmax(outputLabel, 1), tf.int64)}

  if not inferFlag:
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,
                                                 labels=labelTensor),
                                                 name='myLoss')

    l2Loss = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES), name='l2Loss')

    fullLoss = tf.add(loss, l2Loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('fullLoss', fullLoss)

  if trainingFlag:
    globalStep = tf.train.get_global_step()

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()

    updateOps = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(updateOps):
      trainOp = optimizer.minimize(
        fullLoss, global_step=globalStep)
  else:
    trainOp = None

  if not inferFlag:
    evalOp = tf.metrics.accuracy(labelTensor,predictions['prediction'])


  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions, fullLoss, trainOp,
                                  evalOp)
```

I get the following error message:

> **ValueError:** No name available for layer scope because the layer "lstmConv2d" has not been used yet. The scope name  is determined the first time the layer instance is called. You must therefore call the layer before querying 'scope_name'

If I replace the convLSTM2D/static_rnn by any other kind of tf.layer , it works fine (if I use kernel_regularizer=tf.nn.l2_loss)...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this exact error message. But this use of `trainable_weights` is not right anyway because this collection contains *all* variables created inside cells, including the *bias* (which is there due to `use_bias=True`). Regularizing bias is usually not a good idea, as discussed, for instance, [on CV.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/153605/130598).

To get *just* the kernel, do this:

```
variables = [var for var in tf.trainable_variables(convLSTMNet.scope_name) 
             if 'kernel' in var.name]
```

... which grabs everything from the cell scope (which is `'rnn/lstmConv2d'` in your case) and filters only the kernel.

If that doesn't return the variables, the first thing is to checkout is the whole [`tf.trainable_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables) collection; next, make sure LSTM cells have been instantiated in a layer, i.e., check what actual `lstmInput` length is. This will help you narrow down the issue (which is most probably outside of the provided snippet).

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and unfortunately, it didn't work. I get the following error:
ValueError: No name available for layer scope because the layer "lstmConv2d" has not been used yet. The scope name  is determined the first time the layer instance is called. You must therefore call the layer before querying `scope_name`
I think this happens because it is in the model function of an estimator (no graph has been constructed yet?)

Comment: I have run the test: the graph is constructed in model fn and trainable variables get populated. You should provide a **reproducible** example

Answer (score 0):

Your `convLSTMNet` already has a variable name `lstmConv2d` assigned by you.

So just call:

```
myvariables = [var for var in tf.trainable_variables() if  var.name.split('/')[0] in ['lstmConv2d']]
```

You have all variables in the convLSTMNet, you can then sieve the kernel:

```
myvariables = [var for var in myvariables if 'kernel' in var.name]
```